# Need Feedback on JUnit test comparing two timestamps

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I am writng a JUnit test case for the below methods :

```
public final class LoggerService implements ILoggerService {

  private Logger logger;
  
  private <T> LoggerService(T type){
    logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger((Class<?>) type);
  }

  public static <T> LoggerService getLoggerService(T type){
    return new LoggerService(type);
  }

  @Override
  public Long startTimeFrame() {
    return new Date().getTime();
  }

  @Override
  public Long stopTimeFrame(Long startTimeFrame) {
    return new Date().getTime() - startTimeFrame;
  }   
 
  }

}
```

The simple JUnit test is :

```
@Test
public void testStartTimeFrame(){
   LoggerService loggerService = LoggerService.getLoggerService(LoggerServiceTest.class);
   assertEquals(new Date().getTime(), loggerService.startTimeFrame());
}
```

Is this an efficient test case ? Is there any chance that this test could fail sometimes ?
Please suggest how I can improve this

Comment: You could create one timestamp before the call to tested method, and another after the call. Then check that the tested method returned value between those two (inclusive).

Comment: Another option is to introduce a clock interface with method returning current time and use that in your class instead of instantiating a Date directly. And in the test supply a mock implementation and check that the tested method returned whatever the mock returns.

Comment: Your stop method refers to a variable startTimeFrame which doesn't appear to exist.  Please post all of the relevant code...

Comment: Hi I have corrected the code

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is the call to the `new` operator inside your *code under test* (cut). So the way to go is to *inject* this *dependency* into your cut. Of cause the (failed) implementation of the *Java Singelton Pattern* is a [problem](https://williamdurand.fr/2013/07/30/from-stupid-to-solid-code/) too.

By looking at the API of the [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html) class we find that it is *mutable* (which raised lots of discussions when it was introduced). This gives us the opportunity to define a *member variable* of type `Date` and reuse is in all the methods of the cut. Of cause in each method  `Date.setTime(milliseconds)` needs to be called where we pass in `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Of cause this is a new *requirement* to our cut that needs its own UnnitTest methods.

```
 class InjectDateTest {

    static class LoggerService {

        private Date date;

        public LoggerService(Date date) {
            this.date = date;
        }

        public Long startTimeFrame() {
            date.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
            return date.getTime();
        }

    }

    private LoggerService loggerService;
    private Date loggerDate = new Date();

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws Exception {
        loggerService = new LoggerService(loggerDate);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldSetTimeAfterCall() throws InterruptedException {
        long creationTime = loggerDate.getTime();       
        Thread.sleep(200, 0);
        loggerService.startTimeFrame();
        assertTrue(creationTime < loggerDate.getTime(),
                String.format("time in date object %s < %s", creationTime, loggerDate.getTime())
                );
    }

    @Test
    public void testStartTimeFrame() {
        Long startTimeFrame = loggerService.startTimeFrame();
        assertEquals(loggerDate.getTime(), startTimeFrame);
    }

}
```

Comment: So here are we not instantiating  the "LoggerService"  object  from the Java Module ( Not the inner static class inside Test Class) . I'm little confused as both the names are same - 'LoggerService'

Comment: @user3254725: I simply wanted to provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that you can directly paste to your IDE in one shot.

Answer (score 4):

### Test-ability

@Timothy Truckle and @slepic have both given you some good suggestions about how you can improve your test and the test-ability of your class.  There are various other ways that could be used to make the class more testable, however the thing that struck me was that the `LoggerService` didn't seem to make a lot of sense.

### A Logging Service?

There's three public methods `getLoggerService`, `startTimeFrame` and `stopTimeFrame`.  The `getLoggerService` creates a new instance, fine, but start/stop time frame don't feel like they belong in a logger class.  Start returns an actual start time, whereas stop returns a delta from a time that the client has to supply.  To me this behaviour feels wrong, and because we can't see the client it's unclear why it would be structured this way.  Both methods feel like they belong more in a stopwatch (or similar) class rather than a logger.  The `@Override` suggests these methods are coming from `ILoggerService`, is this a class you own, or does it come from a library somewhere?

I also find it particularly weird that a `LoggerService` class doesn't appear to provide any way to access the `logger` it creates, or in fact do any logging related activity at all.

### Boxing

As an aside, `getTime()` returns a `long`.  If you do own the interface, is there a reason why start and stop are boxing the parameters/return values, rather than using the primitive types?

### JUnit

You related [question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67455244/592182) suggests that you're using JUnit 5.  If this is the case, you no longer need to declare you test methods as `public`, annotating them with `@Test` is sufficient for the framework to find them.